Multi-armed bandit with 2 coins: What strategy maximises reward?
What strategy maximises the total reward, on average, after $n$ trials, in this multi-armed bandit:

two coins A and B, with probability of success $p_A$ and $p_B$
reward is $1$ on success, $0$ on failure

I simulated:

UCB, Thompson, Mean
with various priors, e.g. $p_A=p_B=10\% ,50\%, 90\%$
with various number of trials, e.g. $n=8, 16, 32, 64$

In all settings, the "Mean" strategy appears to maximise the total reward, on average. This strategy consists of checking the posterior distributions of $p_A$ and $p_B$ after each trial, and choosing the coin with the highest average probability for the next trial.
Is this correct? What is the intuition?

Is there any actual data here, or are you simulating from Bernoulli distributions with different parameters? In the Bayesian MAB setting we’re interested in the expected reward based on posterior sampling, and the priors are fixed a priori and don’t change at any point during the sampling procedure. The prior on the agent should be a prior over the parameter space of the Bernoulli likelihood, e.g. a beta distribution

@RandySavage thank you! The Bernoulli is simulated. I corrected my question, the prior does not change of course. At every trial, I look at the posterior indeed.

"performed best" how do you measure this?

By strategy you mean optimizing the number of wins, per game? Since optimal might also be a choice to play not at all if these games have negative cost when you loose.

Note that if the priors are the same, the coin with the highest posterior mean will be the one with the most successes so far.  Also, I think you mean "expected total reward", not "total reward", as an objective, since the total reward itself is random.

@jbowman thanks! I added "maximizes on average" to convey the same meaning

@SextusEmpiricus thank you! I fixed "performed best" with a more clear statement.   There is no negative cost, because the reward is 0 or 1. Never negative. See above.

With respect to the limited set of alternatives you've explored, it may be correct, especially if the priors are the same and the two probabilities are quite different. However, in general, the sample mean strategy is not optimal, because it never explores the alternative that seems inferior so as to gain more information about it—it implicitly assumes learning about the alternative has no value—when, obviously, it does, especially when you are just starting out.
This paper - Asymptotically efficient adaptive allocation rules - presents a solution to this problem for the multi-armed Bernoulli bandit case (Example 2.)
A quote from the paper: "While we would like to sample from [the] apparently superior population, we need to make sure that the other populations have been
sampled enough for us to be reasonably confident that they are indeed
inferior."
Let us consider the following rule (without explanation, as it's in the paper and rather lengthy).  We define $n$ to be the total number of stages so far and $n_i$ to be the number of stages where we have observed coin $i\in \{1,2\}$.  We define:
$$a_{n,i} = {\log n \over n_i}$$
and
$$I(x,y) = x \log {x\over y} + (1-x) \log {1-x\over 1-y}$$
Note that $I(x,y)$ is not symmetric in its arguments.
Our decision rule is:

At every odd step, sample from coin $1$ if $\bar{X}_1 > \bar{X}_2$ or $I(\bar{X}_1, \bar{X}_2) < a_{n,1}$

At every even step, sample from coin $2$ if $\bar{X}_2 > \bar{X}_1$ or $I(\bar{X}_2, \bar{X}_1) < a_{n,2}$


We set up an example with $p_1 = 0.4$ and $p_2 = 0.6$, and compare the total rewards over various iteration counts with those of the simpler strategy "choose whichever one has the better history."  The code is rather lengthy, as I've emphasized clarity over efficiency.
library(data.table)

a <- function(n,i) log(n)/i
I <- function(x,y) x*log(x/y) + (1-x)*log((1-x)/(1-y))

p1 <- 0.4; p2 <- 0.6

reward <- data.table(mean = rep(0,1000), robbins = rep(0,1000))
for (j in 1:1000) {  # We repeat everything 1000 times
    
xbar_1 = 0.5; xbar_2 = 0.5
n1 = 1; n2 = 1

for (i in 1:nrow(reward)) {
    if (i %% 2 == 1) {
        if (xbar_1 > xbar_2 | I(xbar_1, xbar_2) < a(i, n1)) {
            result <- rbinom(1, 1, p1)
            xbar_1 = (n1*xbar_1 + result) / (n1+1)
            n1 = n1 + 1
        } else {
            result <- rbinom(1, 1, p2)
            xbar_2 = (n2*xbar_2 + result) / (n2+1)
            n2 = n2 + 1
        }
    } else {
        if (xbar_2 > xbar_1 | I(xbar_2, xbar_1) < a(i, n2)) {
            result <- rbinom(1, 1, p2)
            xbar_2 = (n2*xbar_2 + result) / (n2+1)
            n2 = n2 + 1
        } else {
            result <- rbinom(1, 1, p1)
            xbar_1 = (n1*xbar_1 + result) / (n1+1)
            n1 = n1 + 1
        }
    }
    reward$robbins[i] = reward$robbins[i] + result
}

xbar_1 = 0.5; xbar_2 = 0.5
n1 = 1; n2 = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(reward)) {
    if (xbar_1 > xbar_2) {
        result <- rbinom(1, 1, p1)
        xbar_1 = (n1*xbar_1 + result) / (n1+1)
        n1 = n1 + 1
    } else {
        result <- rbinom(1, 1, p2)
        xbar_2 = (n2*xbar_2 + result) / (n2+1)
        n2 = n2 + 1
    }
    reward$mean[i] = reward$mean[i] + result
    }
}
} # End of j loop

Our starting values for $n_1, n_2$ etc. can be thought of as a prior $\mathrm{Beta}(0.5,0.5)$ distribution on the probabilities.
We run this simulation 1000 times and average the results to get more accurate estimates of how the rewards evolve.  We plot the ratio of the Lai-Robbins cumulative rewards to the rewards of the maximum mean decision rule for the first 1000 observations:

As we can see, for the first few observations, the max mean policy outperforms the Lai-Robbins policy, as the latter is engaged in more exploration and less greedy optimization.  However, the improved accuracy of parameter estimates from the exploration rapidly begins to pay off; around observation 10, the Lai-Robbins payoffs start to catch up to the max mean payoffs, and by observation 60 they have exceeded them.
Why does this happen, and why do the two algorithms not converge to the same reward after many iterations?  The following density plot of the results at iteration 1000 helps tell the tale:

We see two peaks in the total reward for the max mean algorithm, one around 400 (corresponding to the expected value of always picking the coin with a 40% probability of heads) and the other around 600 (corresponding to the expected value of always picking the coin with a 60% probability of heads.)  The peak around 400 happens when the initial coin flips, through random chance, favor the 40% coin heavily, e.g., three tails in a row for the 60% coin and four heads in a row for the 40% coin.  After that, we keep choosing the 40% coin, and never revisit the 60% coin, leaving us with a long run expected rate of return of 0.4 per trial.
The Lai-Robbins algorithm, on the other hand, has a far smaller peak at 400, indicating that it does not get stuck choosing the worse coin nearly as often. The price we pay for this is an occasional update of our probability estimate for the 40% coin by choosing it instead of the 60% coin; as a result, we don't achieve quite as high a value in the best cases as we do with the max mean strategy.  Overall, the exploration helps a lot more than it costs.
